# Finding all TR (from html <table>) in [Python]

Tags: python, regex, html-parsing

I want to get all my that's inside .
I wrote this code:

```
matchObj = re.search(r'<tr>(.*?)</tr>', txt, re.M|re.I|re.S)
```

but I only get the first group.

how can I get all groups?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Use an HTML parser. Can will never be smarter than the most dumb HTML parser.

Comment: you should have at least tried "help(re)" match / findall are the basic components of re. Please research a bit before asking on SO>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`findall`

```
matchObj = re.findall(r'<tr>(.*?)</tr>', txt, re.M|re.I|re.S)
```

`search` only finds the first one in the given string.

you can read more about the different methods you can use in [regex](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

however, it looks like you are parsing HTML. why don't you use an [HTMl parser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html)?

Comment: yeah you should use `BeautifulSoup` or something

Answer (score 5):

To get more than one match use `re.findall()`.

However, using regular expressions to parse HTML is going to get ugly and complicated fast. Use a proper HTML parser instead.

Python has several to choose from:

- [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) is part of the standard library
- [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is a popular 3rd party library
- [lxml](http://lxml.de/) is a fast and feature-rich C-based library.

ElementTree example:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

tree = ElementTree.parse('filename.html')
for elem in tree.findall('tr'):
    print ElementTree.tostring(elem)
```

BeautifulSoup example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open('filename.html'))
for row in soup.select('table tr'):
    print row
```

Comment: I'd love to learn why my answer is not helpful or wrong; that way I can improve it!

Comment: it seems someone did not like us answering this question as we have both been down-voted for no reason.

Comment: however both you answered well, I +1'ed both you

Comment: Thanks, @MartijnPieters.  I've added your notes and example to http://htmlparsing.com/python.html for future posting.

Comment: Author didint ask what to use to find tablerows, he asked how to find them with regex. You gave him answer for finding table and not using regex, how good is your answeR?

Comment: @Tommix: I briefly addressed the issue with their regular expression; use `findall` instead of search. It is however *not a good idea* to use regular expressions, not when much better tools are available.

Comment: @Tommix: it is *important* to not just give a man a fish and satisfy todays meal, I teach how to fish as well.